# Matlab loop - sales per year

Tags: matlab

I'm new to matlab, and doing a school projects. 
I importing some data from an excel sheet into my matlab.

Column B from sales (sold cars):

```
20855
57531
180033
175165
109924
62130
144411
46403
```

And column D from models (salesprice):

```
1.7707e+05
2.0652e+05
182407
157591
1.4868e+05
2.0829e+05
1.7230e+05
1.7131e+05
```

You can see the imports here:

```
global Models Production Sales;

[~, ~, Production]=xlsread('data/Production.xlsx');
[~, ~, Models]=xlsread('data/Models.xlsx');

[sP] = cell2mat(Models(2:size(Models),4))
[ppy] = cell2mat(Production(2:size(Production),2))
```

I then needed to calculate to total sales amount. 
And I did it by doing this:

```
[sP] = cell2mat(Models(2:size(Models),4))
[spy] = cell2mat(Sales(2:size(Sales),2))

car1 = spy(1).* sP (1)
car2 = spy(2).* sP (2)
car3 = spy(3).* sP (3)
car4 = spy(4).* sP (4)
car5 = spy(5).* sP (5)
car6 = spy(6).* sP (6)
car7 = spy(7).* sP (7)
car8 = spy(8).* sP (8)

sumCar = car1+car2+car3+car4+car5+car6+car7+car8
```

sP = salesprice spy = sales per year

As you can see, this is a very manual approach, and I would need to update the code if a car9 was introduced to the spreadsheet.

So I was wondoring if there was a way of doing this by including a loop and iterate ower my columns instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also relatively new to MATLAB, but I am pretty sure you can use a for loop.
Something like this:

```
    for i1 = 1:length(spy)
        car(i1) = spy(i1).* sP(i1);

        sumCar = sumCar + car(i1);
    end
```

Try without sumCar in the loop first, to check the loop works, then add in the code for sumCar.

If it does not work with the loop I think you could do:

```
    sumCar = sum(car);
```

Which will add all the elements in the array/vector together along one dimension. So it should work as long as the vector is one-dimensional.

You can look [here](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) for more info.

Hope that helped in some way.

Answer (score 0):

I defined the vectors like this

```
sP = [20855  57531 180033 175165 109924 62130 144411 46403];
spy = [1.77E+09 2.07E+09 182407 157591 1.49E+09 2.08E+09 1.72E+09 1.71E+09]
```

Then do this, is faster and easier:

```
sumCar = spy * sP';
```

It use the [Matrix Multiplication](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mtimes.html) of Matlab.